# Яндекс Карты по координатам в модальном окне

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, bootstrap4

Почему функция ymaps не видит координаты?

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Mars14/f8Lwac9q/47/)

jQuery:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var lat = $(this).data('LA');    
var long = $(this).data('LO');
    
    function init (lat, long)
    {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map',
        { 
            center: [lat, long],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: ["zoomControl", "fullscreenControl"]
        });
       
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Orders</h1>
 <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<table class="table table-striped"> <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-LA="30" data-LO="40" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-LA="35" data-LO="45" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-LA="40" data-LO="50" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
         <h3>Order</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
  
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глобальные переменные lat и long видны в функции карты init без дополнительных манипуляций: http://jsfiddle.net/Lof0p1qg/

```
 ymaps.ready(init);
    var lat = 55.8
    var long = 37.7;
    function init () {
...
```

Однако вы некорректно работаете с картой. Она инициализируется и отрисовывается в скрытом модальном окне с самого начала. И ей для этого требуются координаты центра, которые ещё не готовы.

Вам следует задать базовые координаты с самого начала, а не после нажатия на таблицу. Поэтому необходимо задать ей хоть какой-то стартовый центр, чтобы устранить ошибку. А уже в дальнейшем организовать смену центра карты через [setCenter](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map.html#method_detail__setCenter).

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! Теперь пытаюсь реализовать setCenter  с координатами полученными из таблицы (точнее уже из ячейки). Но пока без успеха. Функция setCenter работает сразу после отрисовки карты ( я вставил функцию только для проверки функционала). А вот далее пытаюсь с помощью on shown.bs.modal получить координаты, но не получается. (http://jsfiddle.net/Mars14/f8Lwac9q/185/)